# Laravel Socialite Github provider email is null

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, github-api, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to setup login in Laravel with GitHub using Socialite.

Here is my provider callback function:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $provider_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    dd($provider_user);
    if($provider_user->email) {
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'email' => $provider_user->email
        ], [
            'name' => $provider_user->name ?? $provider_user->nickname,
            'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(16)),
        ]);
        Auth::login($user, true);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

When I `dd` the user that provider returns, I can see that values `$provider_user->name` and `$provider_user->nickname` are correct, but `$provider_user->email` is `null`.

Which, according to the GitHub API documentation shouldn't be the case, as my e-mail is public:
[image]
[image]

I have tried `https://api.github.com/user/emails` where I've tried putting user nickname, as well as client ID in place of `user`, but to no avail. The response is:

`{ "message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest" }`

So, am I doing something wrong or GitHub API simply no longer returns e-mail addresses? Is there a way to get a public e-mail address?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem earlier.
What I did upon creating the github app is change the User permissions->Email addresses to read only. You can update it on the permission & events:

[image]